# Food/production for Domestic trade routes

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

In Civilization 5, how is the amount of **food** or **production** received from *domestic trade routes* calculated?

Comment: what type of trade routes are we talking about? Is it from roads/ports or from caravans/cargo ships?

Comment: @UlfricStormcloak Caravans/cargo ships. Those can produce f/p on the target city.

Answer (score 2):

They are static rates (not affected by tech/buildings/etc).  It's 4 for land routes and 8 for ships.  The base city doesn't lose that food or production, the other city just gains it, which is nice.

**EDIT:** The 4/8 number is a base value.  It increases incrementally by a value of .5 for each age advancement starting at Renaissance era (need to check the age to be sure, will test in a game when I get a chance).

Comment: In my current game in the atomic era (normal speed), it's 12 for ships and 6 for caravans, so there is something else involved.

Comment: Is it out of your capital?

Comment: No, it's for all destinations.
Atomic era, 17 cities, 10 trade routes available. 12 food per ship.

Comment: Hooray for science! I just moved to the information era and my f/p per trade route increased to 13 & 6,5.

Comment: @EeroAaltonen So we've found the missing link, moving up in eras must give a .5 increase to the base allotment past a certain era.

Comment: I am looking at an ancient era caravan opportunity, which would net 3 food per turn.

Comment: There is a doctrine increasing it (+50%) too (3rd/last row of Order).